# Java - Box SDK - BoxItem.getInfo().getTags() is empty when it shouldn't be

Tags: box-api, box

When I use the Box java api, the `BoxInfo.tags` seems always empty, even when i know there are tags on the object.

Is there some way to get them?

`List<String> tags = item.getInfo().getTags();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops i forgot

`BoxItem.Info info = item.getInfo(BoxItem.ALL_FIELDS);`

tags aren't returned by default.